# How to show Silverlight Toolkit Busy Indicator during calculation?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, busyindicator

I'm having some problems implementing a control that shows a Busy indicator, here is the scenario: I have a simple View with a busy indicator and a TextBlock, this bind to a ViewModel (that is something like the following).

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private bool _isbusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isbusy; }
        set
        {
            _isbusy=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
        }
    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public void CallMe()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        Text = Static.PerformCalculation();
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

So far all pretty simple, no?? The problem is when i have a method like CallMe(). I have to show and hide the busy indicator while the calculation is being done, i thougth that the reason was that the calculations and the IsBusy property notifications where done on the same thread, so i came out with something like this:

```
public void CallMe()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    Static.PerformCalculationAsync(CalculationCallback);
}

private void CalculationCallback(string result)
{
    Text = result;
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Now something different happen, the Busy Indicator loads fine, but when the calculation is too short the BusyIndicator isn't shown and there is a small delay between the CallMe() method called and the Text appears on the screen. *This is my problem, i want that the Text property gets calculated (and shown on the screen) before the BusyIndicator gets hidden.*

**Does anyone know a good way to do this, or has any advice that i can follow??**

Comment: Just to be sure: on your busyindicator control you have set the following? DisplayAfter="0"

Comment: can't belive i was missing that, thanks that solves my problem :)

Comment: @emp: Even though the answer is short its still an answer.  Please add answers using the answer box instead of using a comment.  It would allow question then to appear in the list of questions as having had an answer and by now probably marked as answered thereby saving others the time and trouble of reading the question with a view to answering only to find that in effect it is already done and dusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `busyindicator` control needs

```
DisplayAfter="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar problem where, busy indicator was shown forever sometimes and looks like the problem is resolved by setting `DisplayAfter` to "0".

**Step 1.** Showing busy indicator and then invoking a javascript function:

```
BusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("foo", id);
```

**Step 2.** Javascript function does a post back and once the post back is completed, it calls Silverlight function to close the busy indicator by setting:

```
BusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
```

**Problem:** javascript function calls silverlight function to close the busy indicator before the busy indicator is really shown on the UI (though we have set `IsBusy` to true before invoking javascript).

**Solution:** I have observed that `DisplayAfter` value was set to `00.00.00.1` in xaml and I have changed to

```
BusyIndicator.DisplayAfter = TimeSpan.Zero
```

in code behind. This has solved my problem. But I want to check whether `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke` is a synchronous or asynchronous call?

Thanks for your inputs